# Saving values in json file with superagent and reactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have an app that allows me to save my comment to a json file. Given the author, if I submit my comment, it will enter to the comments.json. I am using reactJS and supeagent.

this is the code handles the view and runs in localhost:3001

```js
class App3 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      text: "",
      author: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    //
    var commentUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api/comments";
    Request.get(commentUrl).then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        id: response.body.id,
        author: response.body.author,
        text: response.body.text,
      });
    });
    //
    e.preventDefault();
    var newItem = {
      id: Date.now(),
      author: this.state.name,
      text: this.state.text
    };
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      items: prevState.items.concat(newItem),
      text: ''
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div  className="app3">
        <div className="col-sm-4">
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <h1>Comments</h1>
            <div className="commentsSection">
            <AddComment items={this.state.items} />
            </div>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <textarea className="textarea" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.text} />
              <button className="btn btn-default">Comment</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      );
    }
  }

class AddComment extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {this.props.items.map(item => (
        <p className="itemComment"  key={item.id}>{item.text}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

and this handles the json file which runs at localhost:3000

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

var COMMENTS_FILE = path.join(__dirname, 'comments.json');

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// Additional middleware which will set headers that we need on each request.
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // Set permissive CORS header - this allows this server to be used only as
    // an API server in conjunction with something like webpack-dev-server.
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
    next();

    // Disable caching so we'll always get the latest comments.
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    next();
});

app.get('/api/comments', function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile(COMMENTS_FILE, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      process.exit(1);
    }
    res.json(JSON.parse(data));
  });
});

app.post('/api/comments', function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile(COMMENTS_FILE, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      process.exit(1);
    }
    var comments = JSON.parse(data);
    // NOTE: In a real implementation, we would likely rely on a database or
    // some other approach (e.g. UUIDs) to ensure a globally unique id. We'll
    // treat Date.now() as unique-enough for our purposes.
    var newComment = {
      id: Date.now(),
      author: req.body.author,
      text: req.body.text,
    };
    comments.push(newComment);
    fs.writeFile(COMMENTS_FILE, JSON.stringify(comments, null, 4), function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
      }
      res.json(comments);
    });
  });
});


app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Server started: http://localhost:' + app.get('port') + '/');
});
```

and my comments.json file only have `{}`.

Comment: I think, `handleSubmit` should be `Request.post(commentUrl).then((response) ...`

Answer (score 0):

I should've read the documentation of [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) first 
on handleSubmit event i added this

```
  Request.post('http://localhost:3000/api/comments')
         .send({
          author: this.props.name,
          text: this.state.text
        })
```